# HMM rolling estimation different from batch estimation

Tags: python, markov-process, hidden-markov-model

I'm using the GuassianHMM from the python package hmmlearn 
and after fitting the hmm to the data the predictions that are done in one batch

```
hm = GaussianHMM(n_components=3,random_state=19)
preds = hm.predict(myData)
```

seem to be different then the ones that i am doing on a rolling window

```py
low_bound = 0
rolling_preds =[]

for i in range(20,myData):
     rolling_preds.append(hm.predict(myData[low_bound:i+1])[-1])
     low_bound = low_bound +1 

#Creating a window of size 20 and sliding it over the data

preds = preds[20:]
#making the batch predictions the same size as the rolling predictions

len(rolling_preds) == len(preds)
>>>> True

Counter(rolling_preds == preds)
>>>> Counter({True:7000,False:1000})
```

The reason I am doing rolling predictions is because I'm trying to simulate how the model would behave in a live system scenario,and as suspected the performance drops significantly.

I tried a different window approach without the low_bound variable, so the window would just expand indefinitely the results are very similar however.

What is quite interesting is when i fit the hmm with the sequence parameter

`hm.fit(myData,[sequence_length for i in range len(data)])`*

- the sequence_length has to be evenly divisible by the length of your data

and then feed the predictions this way

```py
low_bound = 0 
rolling_preds = []
for i in range(sequence_length,len(myData)):
    rolling_preds.append(hm.predict(myData[low_bound:i+1])[-1])
    low_bound = low_bound +1
```

When using this approach where the length of the data I am predicting is equal to the sequence length that the model was trained on the hmm just gives wildly wrong predictions.

for example if the numper of components was 3 
this approach would give estimations of really large numbers (-48994798,48994798) or just 10

any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Vitrebi algorithm uses all the data for prediction, that's why the predictions change when doing them on a rolling basis, possible fix is to re fit the hmm on a window basis.